# Can we store different locators ( xpath, css, id, name) types for same web element variable in one single POM page

Tags: java, maven, selenium, pom.xml

Can we store different locators ( `xpath`, `css`, `id`, `name`) types for same web element variable in one single `POM` page. I know, we cant store different locators with same logical name inside `POM` class `file.POM` page , but can we refer to same logical name with different locators type??

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 different options as explained below

Assume there is a save button in the page

1. Define all the 4 methods to click and call which ever method u want

   myPage.save.clickbyXPath 
   myPage.save.clickbyCSS
   myPage.save.clickbyName
   myPage.save.clickbyId
2. Pass the parameter to POM

   myPage.save.click (clickby)  // clickby "xPath", "CSS", "id", "name"

In side POM use switch to call the appr method.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution on my own which is better for testing application with changing UI on new release.

The solution is to use @FindAll annotation inside POM page, so that we can link different locators for one single logical name. In future if xpath fails then may be ID or name or Css selector will work, Which in fact reduces the rework of changing Object Repository.